# Does it cost more to run a refrigerator on an extension cord?

Tags: electrical

My new mini refrigerator is plugged into a 50 ft extension cord that is plugged into my house.
Does it cost more to run because of the cord?

Comment: Yes - you're losing some power  in the cord. But it's probably negligible depending on how much power your refrigerator uses, and how big the wires are in the cord.

Comment: @Johnny Are you sure? The voltage at the house end is the same, so "more power" means the lower voltage at the refrigerator causes the refrigerator to draw more current. I'm a bit dubious.

Comment: Need more data, like fridge specs and extension cord wire size. Also, what  type of electrical service in the country in question. A more important consideration than electricity cost would be if a voltage drop across the long cord is damaging the electric motor on the appliance. Check the refrigerator owner's manual, it will give maximum cord distance/wire gauge recommendations.

Comment: @DanielGriscom The voltage is only the same at the other end with no load, every (real world) wire has resistance, so when it carries current it will have a voltage drop. But, like I said it may be negligible. For example, with a very lightweight 18 gauge cord and a refrigerator that draws 5 amps when in use, the voltage drop would be [around 3V](http://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html), so it'd be losing around 15W in the cord. (or around 2.5% of the power used by the 'fridge). For a more significant load, say a 12A hair dryer, the voltage drop would be around 7V.

Comment: @Johnny The question is whether it "costs more to run", i.e. whether the system uses more power. So, this means adding an extension cord and cutting the voltage at the fridge must cause the fridge to draw more current. Otherwise the power emitted by the cord is balanced by the reduced power (perhaps with reduced reliability) taken by the fridge.

Comment: @Daniel, if some power is lost in the cord, the refrigerator will run longer or cycle more often to achieve the same longer term cooling effect.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Why? Refrigerator compressors are driven by constant-speed motors, right? So, the same amount of energy will go into the compressor, and it will cool just as fast. (Side note: this is **way** off-topic for this site, so I'm going to drop the subject as unresolved.)

Comment: @Daniel: moving heat from a 5C space to a 20C space takes n Joules per hour. Heating a 50m cord takes m Joules per hours more than a 2m cord does. m + n > n. QED.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick re: "..the refrigerator will run longer or cycle..."  Compressors and other electrical items actually draw power until they are satisfied or the breaker trips. So, the fridge is not at lower power; the total power being consumed doesn't change for the compressor. Loss from the cord adds a little to the bill.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Continued... But, whether it runs longer is actually a good question... with a limited amount of power available (like from a battery), the voltage drop results in lower power, multiplied over a longer amount of time so the power used would be the same, except the efficiency of the compressor would probably be compromised, and since heat is leaking into the fridge with time, it will continue to fight even longer.

Comment: Power consumtion is about balance (rate of cooling vs rate of un-cooling). A snap-chill would be more efficient if the energy for cooling was a linear function, but it is actually exponential. Or if the fridge was perfectly insulated, then the slower it cooled the more efficient it would be (efficient at making eggs spoil anyway).

Comment: Mandy, I would just put my beer in it and not worry about it. The amount of difference probably won't buy you a beer per year. (Hey I'm a poet). 

Comment: @ArchonOSX I agree, this whole conversation is a bit ridiculous.

Comment: How about you look at your previous post?

Comment: Note that (semi) permanent extension cords are not recommended, as it's too easy to not notice damage. If it goes across a floor, it could be damaged over time from people stepping on it. If it goes around a corner, the insulation could end up wearing away there. I suggest being careful about placement, and inspecting the cord once a month or so.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it does cost you money using the extension cord.

Grabbing a random number out of the air, let's say the fridge draws 2 amperes. If you have a 50 ft. 16 AWG cord, that's 1.996 watts. If the cord was 50 ft. 14 AWG, that'd be 1.256 watts.

Using the energy star standard of $0.12 per KWh. The 16 AWG cord costs you $0.00023952 per hour, while the 14 AWG cord would cost $0.00015072 per hour.

There's also the problem that the manufacturer's documentation likely tells you not to use an extension cord.

***NOTES:***
- I have no idea how much current a mini fridge draws, so I simply grabbed a number out of the air. If somebody wants to comment with a realistic number, I'll rerun the calculations.

---

Using @CarlWitthoft's calculation of 0.7 amperes, and resistance values from NEC chapter 9 table 8. The cost can be figured as follows.

## 18 AWG cord

`VD = Length x 2 x current x ohms per foot`
`VD = 50' x 2 x 0.7 A x 0.00795 ohms`
`VD = 100 x 0.7 A x 0.00795 ohms`
`VD = 70 x 0.00795 ohms`
`VD = 0.5565 volts`

`Watts = Volts x Amperes`
`W = 0.5565 V x 0.7 A`
`W = 0.38955 watts`
`kW = 0.00038955`

`Cost = kW x $/kW`
`Cost = 0.00038955 x $0.12`
`Cost = $0.000046746`

## 16 AWG cord

`VD = 70 x 0.00499 ohms`
`VD = 0.3493 volts`

`W = 0.3493 V x 0.7 A`
`kW = 0.00024451`

`Cost = 0.0002445 kW x $0.12`
`Cost = $0.0000293412`

## 14 AWG cord

`VD = 70 x 0.00314 ohms`
`VD = 0.2198 volts`

`W = 0.2198 V x 0.7 A`
`kW = 0.00015386`
`Cost = 0.00015386 kW x $0.12`
`Cost = $0.0000184632`

So for every hour the fridge is actually running, you'll pay the above amount extra because of the cord.

---

If you're using the 18 AWG cord, and the fridge runs constantly for a year. The power lost to the cord would only cost about $0.40.

`$0.000046746 x 24 hours = $0.001121904`
`$0.001121904 x 365 days = $0.40949496`

So basically, reading this ridiculous answer has likely cost you more than the cord will.

Comment: "Per hour" - of the compressor running, so an accurate calculation requires knowledge of the duty cycle of the compressor in your conditions.

Comment: Right, because you only have voltage drop during the duty cycle.  10A@10% will be 25 times the loss than 2A@50%.  Since loss in watts is proportional to current squared.

Answer (score 3):

Pulling some stats from advertised products:

> Gauge Conductors: 16/3 SJO Cord Length: 50 ft. Color: Black Watts:
>   1625 watts OSHA Listed: Yes Plug Type: Grounded Number of Outlets: 1
>   Maximum Amperage: 13 amps

AWG rating:  4.016 ohms/1000 ft  , or  0.4016 ohms for your 50-footer, round trip.  Using I^2R, which isn't exactly correct for AC due to phase shifting, you'd get  0.4016 watts per amp drawn.

Looking at ratings page found somewhere:

> Compact refrigerators, typically ranging from 1.7 to 4.4 cubic feet,
>   receive an Energy Star rating when they consume no more than 239.42
>   kilowatt-hours per year for manual defrost versions, or up to 318.4
>   kWH/year for units with partial automatic defrost.

So let's pick a conservative 365 kW-h/yr because that's a nice clean 1 kW-h/day :-), and at a conservative (IMHO) 50% duty cycle that's  1kWh/(24/2) = 83.3 watts when running.  83 watts --> roughly 0.7 amps @ 120 V.

All of which means I'd cut Tester101's conclusions significantly both because I think he overestimated the extension cord's power loss and because I grabbed a different estimate of the power drawn by the fridge.   YMMV

Answer (score 3):

No. It's a poor way to hook up a permanent load, but it does not waste anything like "as much power as the fridge uses" - it might cost you in life of the fridge, due to low voltage when the compressor is starting making it fail sooner than it should - but that would depend in part on the gauge (size) of the wire in the cord.

Comment: If it is a heavy duty cord it may not cause a low voltage problem but most are not.+ for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The very best way to answer your question is to purchase an energy measuring device and compare power consumption at the house end with the refrigerator connected directly at the house and then connect the refrigerator at the end of the long cord. Keep the measuring device in the same location for both of the comparison measurements.

One device you could consider is the Killawatt meter that can be found online or at many hardware stores. It can show voltage, current and kilowatts consumed.

Comment: You'll need either two of these devices or two very long test periods to get a reliable result.  We're looking for maybe a 1% difference.

Comment: At least 24 hours per test.   If the difference is hard to detect, that is not a detection failure, it is the answer.